# Trying to find the DNN Platform community version that matches my DNN Professional install

Tags: migration, dotnetnuke

I am trying to migrate my DNN 7.* to Community Edition (for the dev server only), and I am trying to find out which Community Edition version matches my professional version. I was hoping to find a table that would map Professional to Community versions, but I haven't been able to find anything. Anyone knows where I can find that information?

Answer (score 0):

The Numbers for the Professional Edition match the Community (Platform) edition exactly. So if you are on DNN PE 7.0.6, get DNN 7.0.6